# Firebase Storage not working on iMessage extension

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage, imessage

I am trying to integrate Firebase into an iMessage extension.

As a test, I am setting up Firebase and trying to save a local file to Firebase Storage in the `viewDidAppear` method. The Firebase Real-time Database works fine in the code below, only the storage part does not.

The exact same code works when done in a normal app (*i.e. not a iMessage extension*).

I get the following error message:

```
Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 
"An unknown error occurred, please check the server response." 
UserInfo={ResponseErrorDomain=NSURLErrorDomain, object=test.jpg,
bucket=myapp.appspot.com, ResponseErrorCode=-995, 
`NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred, please check the server response.
```

I am doing the following:

```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    FIRApp.configure()

    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInAnonymously { (user, error) in
      guard let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension:"jpg") else { return }

      let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("test.jpg")
      storageRef.putFile(fileURL, metadata: nil) { (metaData, error) in  //produces error
        if error != nil {
          print(error.debugDescription) 
        }
      }
      FIRDatabase.database().reference().updateChildValues(["someKey" : "someValue"]) // works fine

    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you try `putData` instead of `putFile`? I have a suspicion that iMessage extensions may get limited access to the file system (since they live in a different sandbox than the normal app), and this getting the file wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! You're suspicions were right, putData works perfectly. Thanks a lot! If you write an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a suspicion that iMessage extensions may get limited access to the file system (since they live in a different sandbox than the normal app), and thus getting the file wouldn't work. In this case `putData` works, but `putFile` doesn't. Solution: always upload and download in memory (`putData` and `dataWithMaxSize:`) vs the file system (`putFile` and `writeFile`).