# Swift: Uploading a file to Firebase Storage from a Share Extension

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an image to firebase storage from a share extension in iOS, I have authed and am communicating with the database but when I attempt to upload the file it fails straight away.

I have made sure that the code that I am using works by using it in my main app. I have also made sure that the file is being saved in the file manager prior to being uploaded correctly.

Here is the code for saving the file prior to the upload:

```
if let data = downsizeImage(image: image).jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2) {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    let url = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.<DOMAIN>.imageShare")?.appendingPathComponent("ImageToSend.jpg")
    do {
          try data.write(to: url!)
        }
    catch {
          print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
}
```

Here is the code for the upload task:

```
let storageRef: StorageReference = Storage.storage().reference().child(storageLocation).child(UUID().uuidString)

var completed = false
var mediaUploadTask: StorageUploadTask?
let mediaTimeoutTask = DispatchWorkItem{ () in
            if !completed {
                    mediaUploadTask?.cancel()
                }
}

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 30, execute: mediaTimeoutTask)
mediaUploadTask = storageRef.putFile(from: mediaUrl, metadata: nil) {(metadata, error) in
completed = true
...
}
```

What should happen is the image is successfully uploaded and the function would continue as normal. What actually happens is the upload fails nearly straight away. Here is the error returned:

```
Printing description of error:
▿ Optional<Error>
  - some : Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response." 
UserInfo={bucket=link-ages-55880.appspot.com,
 _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=BackgroundUploadTask <AC5EADEA-6257-4C32-9454-17626156AA15>.<1>,
 object=media/4qnjSBKysi79uCR3cTzf/04D22317-D2C0-4A5C-B032-4F37DB2C8F7A,
 _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "BackgroundUploadTask <AC5EADEA-6257-4C32-9454-17626156AA15>.<1>"
), 
NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred, please check the server response., 
ResponseErrorDomain=NSURLErrorDomain, ResponseErrorCode=-995}
```

If anyone has any idea what the problem might be, your ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is a screenshot of the debugger:
[image: Debugger Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

I have found out what the problem was. Due to the way that iOS sandboxing works, calling:

```
storageRef.putFile(from: mediaUrl, metadata: nil, completion: {(metadata, error) in})
```

fails. More info Here: [Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39693142/9882015).

Instead calling:

```
storageRef.putData(Data, metadata: nil, completion: {(metadata, error) in})
```

worked as intended.

Comment: And how do you upload data bigger than 120 MB ??  (such as Videos, for example). It seems that RAM-size-limit for a ShareExtension is 120MB. How do you have to proceed for larger Data ?